# unmet dependencies with linux-tools-common

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, package-management

When i try to install a (random) package i got the following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-tools-3.2.0-24 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried :

```
apt-get -f install
```

And i got the following error message :

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/69.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 183 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 183468 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-tools-common (from .../linux-tools-common_3.2.0-25.40_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.2.0-25.40_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/perf.1.gz', which is also in package linux-base 3.4ubuntu2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.2.0-25.40_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do next?

---

**EDIT:**

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1008713

**EDIT2:**

I manage to remove the error rebooting ubuntu in the recovery mode and i ran dpkg Repair broken Package

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't say how you tried to install,  but here is what I did.

I just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on the keyboard to open Terminal. When it opened, I ran run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-3.2.0-25
```

And that worked with no errors.  I'm running 12.04 updated just a few minutes ago.

You can also install Linux Tools from USC

[image]

***Make sure you have the correct Kernel version before you install, because this is version specific.***

Try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To fix dependencies problems, Try these commands:

1. Update your sources.list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Clean any partial packages left behind during the wreckage.

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```
3. Clean your apt-cache

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```

And try the installation again.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot install new package, because dependencies are broken. (I did what you asked with the version 3.2.0-24, but i got the same error message as before)

Comment: `autoclean` doesn't do anything that isn't also done by `clean`. In particular, it doesn't clean up any files from partially installed packages. If you're running `clean`, you don't need to use `autoclean` as well. See [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a program like [gdebi [image: Install gdebi]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi). That could solve your problem, as this program downloads and installs unmet dependencies for packages.

`gdebi` is usually already installed on your Ubuntu system. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksu gdebi` (or on Kubuntu, `kdesudo gdebi`), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.